# Group parallel stages in Jenkins Pipeline view

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a stage that looks like this:

```
stage('Tests') {
    parallel {
        stage('Test a') {
            //
        }
        stage('Test b') {
            //
        }
        stage('Test c') {
            //
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

It goes on and on, tens of parallel stages. In Blue Ocean this looks fairly nice and usable, but in Jenkins Pipeline all of these stages are displayed in a row and makes it hard to use day-to-day. Is it possible to group these parallel stages under parent "Tests" stage in Jenkins Pipeline view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not available right now. Had the same issue. searched a lot for it.

There are issues created since 2016 around this. But no definitive action has been taken. You can have a look at the issues

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33185